# How to experiment with Kur source code?

Tags: python

**What is the problem?**

1. I want to use the deep-learning system [Kur](https://kur.deepgram.com/index.html) beyond its doc examples
2. Kur's doc at the moment (recently progressed to v0.4) can't help me go very far

**Why source code?**

1. Source code provides best documentation
2. Kur still needs time to grow its doc

**How to play?**

Here are two simple methods of playing suggested by Adam Sypniewski of Kur: one, use a lot of `logger.debug` or `logger.info` to a function for example; the other, if you want to execute a function as a standalone piece of code, just [mocking](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) the "missing" pieces (including things like args, self, etc.)

For the first method, for example, you can go to `__main__.py` to hack `kur -v --version` by inserting the line marked with `###` below:

```
def version(args):    
    """ Prints the Kur version and exits.
    """
    print('Kur, by Deepgram -- deep learning made easy')
    print('Version: {}'.format(__version__))
    print('Homepage: {}'.format(__homepage__))
    logger.info("I am hacking here") ###
```

then, save this file, and run `kur -v --version` to see.

**Why want to learn to test function using testing library like `mock` and `pytest`?**

At the moment, I am using `logger.info` to find out what is going on inside major functions of Kur or any place where I can put a `logger.info` without an error. I think it can help me going for a while.

However, what if in some functions I cannot put a `logger.info` to?

My assumption is testing code is to investigate the inner working of a function from a different approach than `logger.info`. I am tempting to believe that reading and playing codes in `test/` can help me understand or investigate better these functions being tested.

If it is possible, here comes my question below...

**How to start to play kur/test/test_executor.py for a better understand of those functions being tested?**

For example, kur uses [`pytest` in `test_executor.py`](https://github.com/deepgram/kur/blob/master/tests/model/test_executor.py) to test functions inside `kur/kur/model/executor.py`. But I don't know how to start to play with `test_executor.py`

could you help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is this about how to use mock functions for testing? If so, that's a general mechansim that is not specific to Kur.

Comment: Thanks for your request, I will rephrase this part of question soon.

Comment: hi @Schmuddi, I hope it makes more sense now. please have a look